# record Linux Wayland/DRM screen using ffmpeg's kmsgrab device with superimposed webcam

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, twitch, vaapi

Setup is Linux, ffmpeg using kabylake iGPU.

I am capturing a running [sway](https://swaywm.org) instance using the [kmsgrab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#kmsgrab) device, which requires the use of a hardware backend to coherently process the image on my hardware. Only VA API fits this bill. I want to overlay the webcam in the bottom right corner during encoding. However, attempts at manipulating the filter graph to accomplish this have been unsuccessful. This is ultimately for Twitch/Tube stream.

Right now, I am actually capturing the webcam to an sdl window, and simply recording the screen using separate instances of `ffmpeg`. This doesn't actually solve my problem since the window is easily disguised by workspace switching or other windows.

This is the workaround:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# record webcam and open it in sdl window
ffmpeg -v quiet -hide_banner \
  -re -video_size 640X480 -hwaccel vaapi -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i /dev/video0 \
  -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v hevc_vaapi -f hevc - \
  | ffmpeg -v quiet -i - -f sdl2 - &

# wait for webcam window to open
until swaymsg -t get_tree | grep 'pipe:' &>/dev/null; do
  sleep 0.5
done

# position webcam in the bottom right corner of screen using sway
swaymsg floating enable
swaymsg resize set width 320 height 240
swaymsg move position 1580 795
swaymsg focus tiling

#screencast
ffmpeg -format bgra -framerate 60 -f kmsgrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -i - \
  -f alsa -ac 2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i hw:0 \
  -vf 'hwmap=derive_device=vaapi,scale_vaapi=w=1920:h=1080:format=nv12' \
  -c:v h264_vaapi -g 120 -b:v 3M -maxrate 3M -pix_fmt vaapi_vld -c:a aac -ab 96k -threads $(nproc) \
  output.mkv

kill %1
```

Comment: As a further workaround you could fix the window displaying the webcam contents to stay on top all the time through the window manager

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately sway appears to have no such functionality from what I could find in the man page. I'm a long time user of xmonad, but I recently switched to sway since qutebrowser is wayland native.

Answer (score 4):

*in momento*, this may be impossible.

It looks like a limitation in `ffmpeg`'s vaapi backend. I noticed that Intel's QuickSync backend has an `overlay_qsv` filter, yet there is no equivalent `overlay_vaapi`.

In theory, there may be a mechanism to *download* the hardware surface to a software buffer using the `hwdownload` filter once it's been encoded in `hevc_vaapi` so as to make use of the software `overlay` filter to do the superimposition in the last phase of encoding. I will leave this open for now to see if someone can help work toward this end or knows anything more on the topic.

*note on QuickSync:*

After building with QuickSync support and attempting to use *it*, it appears to lack the capability to derive a surface from the `kmsgrab` device resulting in a `function not implemented` error from `ffmpeg`.

Comment: FYI, I also have the same issue with x11grab. Also, I tried to trick it by doing vaapi decode + vaapi scaling + qsv encode but no hope. Somehow it fails to parse `hwmap` filter

Comment: Hello @DrSensor can you share your FFmpeg  command here? I can take a look and work on it.

Comment: There's an overlay filter in Vulkan in FFmpeg, let me see what can be whipped up to enable such a command to work.